# AWS - Setup OIDC authentication in ALB with AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have to setup my application in elastic beanstalk with High availability. My architecture involves a php application running in beanstalk in private subnet with ALB (public subnet) which is also created as part of Beanstalk. I want to have OIDC MYID or Azure AD authentication setup in ALB. How can I do it?

Does beanstalk ALB supports creating oidc authentication also ? or any other way to achieve the OIDC authentication with ALB with application running in beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in the EC2 console and then in the "load balancers" section (look for it near the bottom in the left menu). Here you have a list of all you load balancers. Click on the one you want. You have now the interface for configuration of the listeners. The screen you show is at this place.

Comment: I want to use this alb-oidc authentication. With standalone ALB I get this option but when I use beanstalk I dont see the options for oidc authentication.  - https://developers.onelogin.com/assets/img/blog/inline/aws-alb-oidc.png . Can you suggest here ?

Comment: With your details, I have updated my response with the right answer.

Comment: yes if I create ALB separately I have the option to add oidc authentication, with Beanstalk , it creates its own ALB where I am not able to figure out how to add oidc authetication as I dont see this option in alb rules given by beanstalk ?

Comment: The ALB created by Beanstalk is not different thant others. The only difference is that the configuration is mush more simpler in the EB console than in EC2 console directly. But you can retrieve the load balancer created by EB in the EC2 console and configure it as you want.

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ? If yes, please consider accepting it or upvoting. Thank you